# specialization of template template paremeter of template class for nested template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Normally you can partially specialize a template class against an instantiated template class.  For instance

```
template<class T>
struct specialize_me {};

template<class T>
struct specialize_me<std::vector<T>> {
    static const int foo = 3;
};
```

the template class `specialize_me` is partially specialized against the instantiated template class `std::vector<T>`.  This specialization is selected when `specialize_me` is instantiated with `std::vector<T>`, for any class `T`.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << specialize_me<std::vector<int>>::foo; // Compiles.
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to specialize a template template class against an instantiated nested template class:

```
// Nested template class.
template<class T>
struct Either {
    template<class U>
    struct Or {};
};

template<template<class> class T>
struct specialize_me_2 {};

template<class T>
struct specialize_me_2<Either<T>::template Or> {
    static const int foo = 3;
};
```

In this case, the specialization is *not* selected when I instantiate `specialize_me_2` with the class `Either<T>::template Or` for any class `T`.  My guess is that this happens because the compiler would have to confirm or deny, "There exists a `T` such that `Either<T>::template Or` is the same type as the `specialize_me_2` instantiation" in order to select my specialization, and it is not programmed nor specified to do so.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << specialize_me_2<Either<int>::Or>::foo; // Does not compile.  'foo' is not a member of specialize_me_2<Either<int>::Or>.
}
```

Is there a way to specialize `specialize_me_2` such that the specialization is selected whenever `specialize_me_2` is instantiated with `Either<T>::Or` for any `T`?

This `Either` struct is eventually going to represent an error-carrying type, so `Either<T>` denotes that `T` is the error type, and `Either<T>::Or<U>` denotes that `U` is the type being carried by the successful computation.

If this is impossible, I might still be able to use `#define`s to enable you to define `Either<T>` for each `T` as it is needed, where `#define` also includes the `specialize_me_2` specialization for that particular `Either<T>::Or`.  Indeed, I intend to use the `Either` struct in programs by writing `template<class T> using FooError = Either<Foo>::Or<T>` anyway and then write `FooError<Bar>`, `FooError<Quux>` and so on, so using this wouldn't be a huge break from the intended usage.

Comment: I don't understand this. What is `Or` supposed to be instantiated with in your second example?

Comment: Template argument type deduction only works on the right side of `::`, hence the reason the compiler cannot deduce `T` in `Either<T>::template Or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intriguing problem.

To solve it without too much pain... if you can add new `using` type inside `Or`

```
template <typename T>
struct Either
 {
   template <typename>
   struct Or
    { using specialOrType = T; };
 };
```

then you can add a second template parameter, a typename with `void` as default, in `specialize_me_2`

```
template <template <typename> class C, typename = void>
struct specialize_me_2
 { static const int foo = 2; };
```

and using SFINAE over `specialOrType`

```
template <typename ...>
using myVoidT = void;

template <template <typename> class C>
struct specialize_me_2<C, myVoidT<typename C<void>::specialOrType>>
 {
   using T = typename C<void>::specialOrType;

   static const int foo = 3;
 };
```

you get your working specialization.

Instead of `myVoidT`, starting from C++17, you can obviously use `std::void_t`.

Observe that this way you can't deduce the original `T` type but you can recover it through `specialOrType`.

Observe also that this require (as pointed by aschepler) that `Or<void>` is a valid specialization. If this isn't the case, you should choose another type `X` so that `Or<X>` is a valid specialization for all `Either<T>`. Suppose that, by example, `Or<int>` is a valid specialization for every `Either<T>`, the specialization become

```
template <template <typename> class C>
struct specialize_me_2<C, myVoidT<typename C<int>::specialOrType>>
 {
   using T = typename C<int>::specialOrType;

   static const int foo = 3;
 };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...>
using myVoidT = void;

template <typename>
struct NoEither
 { };

template <typename T>
struct Either
 {
   template <typename>
   struct Or
    { using specialOrType = T; };
 };

template <template <typename> class C, typename = void>
struct specialize_me_2
 { static const int foo = 2; };

template <template <typename> class C>
struct specialize_me_2<C, myVoidT<typename C<void>::specialOrType>>
 {
   using T = typename C<void>::specialOrType;

   static const int foo = 3;
 };

int main ()
 {
    std::cout << specialize_me_2<NoEither>::foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << specialize_me_2<Either<int>::template Or>::foo << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Not bad, but it requires that `Or<void>` is a valid specialization.

Comment: @aschepler - yes... can be a problem... but I hope that exist a type `X` so that `Or<X>` is a valid specialization... uhmmm... maybe is the case to explicit this point in the answer.

Comment: Too bad you can't specialize `template <typename T> template<> struct Either<T>::Or<dummy_tag>`.

Comment: Strictly, by what rule is the specialization of `specialize_me_2` selected for the instantiation `specialize_me_2<Either<int>::template Or>`?  AFAICT, SFINAE applies here for all types *except* `Either<T>::template Or`.  For that type, the base template is a perfectly good match.  How is the overload set ordered?

Comment: @jcarpenter2 - Both templates are matches. But the specialization is, precisely, more specialized. I mean: if a template-template matches the specialization, surely matches also the base template; but if a template-template matches the base templates, not necessarily matches the specialization (see the `NoEither` case: matches the base, not the specialization). So, when a template-template matches also the specialization, the compiler must use the specialization. I don't know if it's clear (sorry but I don't speak English very well).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like T can't be deduced in your specialization from `Either<T>::Or`, passing `T` in as another template parameter appears to make it work, if that is any use too you..

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Either {
    template<class U>
    struct Or {};
};


template<typename U,template<class> class T>
struct specialize_me_2 {};

template<class T>
struct specialize_me_2<T,Either<T>::template Or> {
    static const int foo = 3;
};


int main() {
    std::cout << specialize_me_2<int,Either<int>::Or >::foo; // Does compile
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/TBbBEc)

Which could be made a bit cleaner with a nested type member in `Either` so you use like,

```
using someEitherType = Either<int>;
...
specialize_me_2<someEitherType::type, someEitherType::Or>::foo
```

Or just specialize on Either directly for the first template parameter,

```
template<class T>
struct specialize_me_2<Either<T>,Either<T>::template Or> {
    static const int foo = 3;
};
```

and just pass in

```
specialize_me_2<someEitherType, someEitherType::Or>::foo
```

[Demo2](https://ideone.com/ct4GrX)